# iosプログラミングで外部フレームワークの導入方法について。

Tags: ios, swift

お世話になります。

まず前提として、私はiOSプログラミングに関して初心者です。

`RMPScrollingMenuBarController`というフレームワーク（？）を使いたいのですが、知識がなさすぎてどのように使えばいいのかわからなくなってしました。
https://github.com/recruit-mp/RMPScrollingMenuBarController

もし、使用方法のわかる方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授いただけないでしょうか？

また、私が試したことは以下の通りです。
1. 上記URLの`Installation`に従って、`cocoapods`を用いてインストールした。
2. 上記URLの`Usage`に記載されているコードをコピペしたが、動作せず。（コピペ先の場所があっているかは不明）
3. `xcode`上で`libPods.a`が赤字で表示されていることから、正常に読み込めていないと予想した。色々試してみるが、改善せず。

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 追記：
xcodeのバージョンは、7.0.1です。

Comment: libPods.aが赤字なのはおそらく問題ないです。それ以上のことはこれだけでは判断できません。「Usageに記載されているコードをコピペしたが、動作せず」について、エラーが起こっているならどのようなエラーか（メッセージなど）エラーは起こってないが期待した動きと異なる場合は、どのような動きを期待していて、実際にはどういう動きをしたのか、などを詳しく書いてください。

Comment: cocoapods でインストールした場合、xcodeprojとは別にxcwordspaceが生成され、以後はこちらを利用するようになります。 xcodeprojではなくxcwordspaceを開いていますか？